# Transaction signature generation

Tags: transactions, protocol, development, ecdsa, signature

When one sets up a [transaction](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#tx), the input of the transaction needs to have a script with a signature to show that you can spend those coins. Which fields of the previous and current transactions need to be concatenated into a message and signed to generate a proper signature? Can someone provide some examples?

Comment: Does this thread give any help? http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=50282.0  and verifier here: http://bitsend.rowit.co.uk

Comment: @StephenGornick Well, it gives a couple examples of raw transactions and a way to verify them online, but still doesn't explain how to create such transactions without using the Bitcoin client.

Comment: see 'Signatures & Witnesses' of the following link : https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-create-a-raw-bitcoin-transaction-step-by-step-239b888e87f2

Answer (score 3):

Here and in the following articles I explain how to build and sign a Bitcoin transaction from scratch. There are also C code examples attached:

https://davidederosa.com/basic-blockchain-programming/inside-transactions/

Answer (score 2):

This is done in the Javascript from BlockChain.info:

- http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=40264.msg851062#msg851062

The transaction can then be sent using either of the following:

- http://blockchain.info/pushtx
- http://bitsend.rowit.co.uk/